# Python re.sub group of number after word

Tags: python, twitter

How can I replace 'some n number(example 11 digit of any number)  or some number with word(ex: any character like as12345678iu) to 'resi'?

I try with re.sub but didn't work, thank you...
sorry I just learning python...

```
tweet = re.sub('(re{11}.\d[^\s]+)','resi',tweet)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!! your problem is little unclear, I would suggest to type it out again. Give sample statements and sample outputs!!

Comment: Data input 11 digit number ex: 12345678912 or  ad133849oi (that number or character can be anything random), this number replace with string 'resi'

Comment: so sample output for both would be "resi"..so anything whose lenght is 11 digit should be replace by "resi"

Comment: yes, thank you for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try pattern `r'\b\w{11}\b'`

**Ex:**

```
import re

tweet = "any character like as123456789 or 12345678912"
print( re.sub(r'\b\w{11}\b','resi', tweet) )
```

**Output:**

```
any character like resi or resi
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
st1 = " this is my number 12345678911"

split_st1 = st1.split()
for item in (split_st1):
    if len(item) == 11:
        st1 = st1.replace(item,'resi')
```

Comment: If you found the solution working, you can upvote the answer for future users!!